# troubleshooting splash page browser differentials

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, safari

I have built a splash page for my web application using rails 4.2.4 and decided to test how it renders across a plethora of different browsers.

As you can see from my attached screenshot, it renders perfectly in firefox, opera and chrome.

However in good old safari, the search bar placeholder looks like it has been dragged through a hedge backwards.

How can I best tackle this aesthetic differential in safari.

Is this administered through some sort of media query or advanced CSS component.?

[image: This is the splash page in firefox, opera and chrome]

[image]

> _header.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img alt="Nippon Beauty" class="navbar-brand-icon" src="assets/nippon.svg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What type of Skincare product would you like?">
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--<span style="color: #53100e">| Japanese and South Korean Luxury Skincare</span> 

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li> 
      <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <% else %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

> bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

$body-bg:                          #ecf0f1;
$font-family-sans-serif:           'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$navbar-height:                    70px;
$navbar-default-bg:                white;
$navbar-default-brand-color:       #c0392b;
$brand-primary:                    #c0392b;
$jumbotron-bg:                     white;

@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';

.center {
     text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
     font-weight: bold;
}


.btn-lg {
    padding: 18px 28px;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    }


.jumbotron {
    width: 735px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.container .jumbotron {
    border-radius: 35px;
}


.container {
    width: 1270px;
}




.navbar {
    min-height: 90px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  display: inline-block;
}


.navbar-brand span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align : middle;
    height: 7px;
}


h1, {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: #e22f8f;
}

.row {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}



li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #e22f8f;
  }

a {
    color: #a0616d;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 13px;
}





/*=========================
  search bar 
 ================= */

 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

 body{
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }

 .search {
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
 }

 .searchTerm {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   border: 15px;
   background: #F2F2F2;
   padding: 5px;
   height: 40px;
   border-radius: 8px;
 }

 .searchTerm:focus{
   color: #000000;
 }


 .searchButton {
   position: absolute;  
   right: -50px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background: #a0616d;
   text-align: center;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 20px;
 }



 /*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/

 .wrap{
   width: 35%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 69%;
   left: 45%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }

 /*This code beneath puts the glow round the search placeholder!*/

textarea:focus, input:focus, input[type]:focus, .uneditable-input:focus {   
    border-color: rgba(160, 97, 109, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(160, 97, 109, 0.075) inset, 0 0 13px rgba(160, 97, 109, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```